# sed utility -d functionality in filename listing

Tags: sed, ksh, ls

I want the explanation for the below command as I am not able to understand functionality  of -d in sed

Does it list the file based on the modified time of the file or does it list the files if the count of files is more than 90 in the specified path.

Filename format is same for all the file

```
 Filename: 20171010220002.txt
 FILES_TO_RETAIN=90
 ls -1t /apps/feroz/*.txt|sed "1,${FILES_TO_RETAIN:-90}d"
```

I know function ls and sed. ls functionality is explained below

```
-1 list only the filename
-t list the file based on the modified time, new file will on the top
```

As per man page for sed the explanation for -d is provided below.

```
 -d Delete pattern space. Start next cycle.
```

Comment: read the sed manpage carefully

Answer (score 1):

There is no option `-d` in `sed`. The first parameter to sed is taken as the sed-script.

Here `d` is the command in the sed-script and is one of the `Commands which accept address ranges`.

`1,90` is the address range for the command `d`.

`sed "1,${FILES_TO_RETAIN:-90}d"` will delete line 1 to 90 from the input, which in your case is the file-list

Conclusion: The resulting output is the list of files sorted by modified time (newest on top), excluding the first 90 files (newest ones).

side-note: using `tail +<n>` would do the same (but excluding n-1 lines).